# SonarQube MSBuild runner isn't working with ported FxCop Roslyn rules added to projects

Tags: c#, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarlint

Currently we're running SonarQube analyses during our build proces. We've wanted to run our quality profile locally in Visual Studio 2015. For this we've created a ruleset for Visual Studio and turned on the rules that were enabled in our quality profile. SonarLint has an intergration for this, but the FxCop rules aren't synced (at the moment). When enabled FxCop rules Visual Studio freezes. So this wasn't an option for us.

Another option we've tried is instead of creating a ruleset based on FxCop and Roslyn. Was trying to create a roslyn only ruleset. So we've added the [FxCop port to Roslyn rules](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers/1.2.0-beta2) NuGet package to out projects. But when we ran SonarQube with MSBuild Runner 2.1 we received the following error: `MSBUILD : error : CA0059 : Invalid settings passed to CodeAnalysis task. See output window for details.` We get this error even when we didn't turn on these rules or use the default Microsoft Ruleset.

When I take a look at the MSBuild log I see the following (removed a lot of rules for readability):

```
/rulesetdirectory:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets" 
/rule:"-C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\\Rules" 
/ruleid:"-Microsoft.Performance#CA1820" 
/ruleid:"-Microsoft.Reliability#CA2002" 
/ruleid:"-Microsoft.Usage#CA1816
      -Microsoft.Usage#CA2208" 
/ruleid:"-Microsoft.Usage#CA2216"  
/searchgac /ignoreinvalidtargets 
/forceoutput /successfile /ignoregeneratedcode /saveMessagesToReport:Active,Excluded 
/timeout:120 
/reportMissingIndirectAssemblies

Switch '/microsoft.usage#ca2208" /ruleid' is an unknown switch.

Type 'FxCopCmd.exe /?' for help on command-line arguments.
MSBUILD : error : CA0059 : Invalid settings passed to CodeAnalysis task. See output window for details. 
Code Analysis Complete -- 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

It looks like SonarQube isn't correctly generating the FxCop argument in this situation. Does anyone know a fix for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

I've created a GitHub repro where this problem can be reproduced: https://github.com/mvdiemen/SonarQubeFxCopRoslyn

Comment: Can you share a minimal working (failing) repro with us?

Comment: @Tamas-SonarSourceTeam I've created a repro on Github so the problem can be reproduced. If you have any problems or if you can't reproduce the problem please contact me. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: @Tamas-SonarSourceTeam is it possible to reproduce the issue? Do you have a (quick) fix how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry @mrtentje, I didn't have the time yet, but it's on my short term TODO list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, currently the Scanner for MSBuild does not support running FxCop through Roslyn. The reason is that it exposes rules that are intended to be used by FxCop in a specific way, different than other rules that are passed to Roslyn.

The analyzers that you are using, notably `System.Runtime.Analyzers-1.2.0-beta2`, override the rule set for FxCop using the property `CodeAnalysisRuleSetOverrides`.

MSBuild has the target `CodeAnalysis` which calls `FxCopCmd.exe`. As the `CodeAnalysisRuleSetOverrides` property is defined, `FxCopCmd` will receive as parameters all the rule IDs defined in that property.

The error you posted comes from a typo in the `System.Runtime.Analyzers-1.2.0-beta2` analyzer when defining that property. There is a semicolon missing in `packages\System.Runtime.Analyzers-1.2.0-beta2\build\System.Runtime.Analyzers.props`, which causes `FxCopCmd.exe` to fail.

Note that `CodeAnalysisRuleSetOverrides` overrides the rule set that is defined by the Scanner for MSBuild (through another property, `CodeAnalysisRuleSet`). It is unintended because as a result FxCop will use the rules defined by the analyzers that you use in the project instead of the rules that are active in the Quality Profile defined in the SonarQube server.

I will fix the `target` file used by Scanner for MSBuild to reset the property `CodeAnalysisRuleSetOverrides`.

To use the Scanner for MSBuild, you should remove those analyzers. More information here: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/From+the+Command+Line